# How to infer type using jest enzyme find

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that is wrapped inside a `Provider` and I use Enzyme mount to test it. I would like to infer the type when using `wrapper.find` so I can access the component state and have all types. Here is an example of the code I'm running:

```
const wrapper = mount<Provider>(
  <Provider mocks={mocks}>
    <MyComponent
      foo={bar}
    />
  </Provider>
);

const MyComponentInstance = wrapper.find("MyComponent").instance();

expect(MyComponentInstance.state.isBar).toBe(true);
```

The `MyComponentInstance` is where I would like to get the type inference, so I can later call `MyComponentInstance.state.isBar`.

The `MyComponent` `State` type is defined this way:

```
type State = {
  isBar: boolean
}
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  public state : State = {
    isBar: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#2-a-react-component-constructor) you can also find components by their constructor. So you might want to try the following:

```
const wrapper = mount<Provider>(
  <Provider mocks={mocks}>
    <MyComponent
      foo={bar}
    />
  </Provider>
);

const MyComponentInstance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance();

expect(MyComponentInstance.state.isBar).toBe(true);
```

TypeScript should now be able to infer the type, but whether this works depends on the type definitions that you're using.

Comment: Good! It still does not pick up the state type, but it does infer the component from the `find`. I'll update my question in order to provide more details regarding how I have the component state typed. Hopefully, it will help to get an answer to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: The question was updated adding the component definition.

Comment: I got this working by casting... not sure if there is another way:
```const MyComponentInstance = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance() as MyComponent;```